# Get the user theme

Tags: theming

In my admin page, I have a text field, for which I want to set the default_value as the active theme. I am getting the admin theme. But my requirement is to get the user theme.

Is there some how I could get theuser active theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user default theme could be obtained by

```
variable_get('theme_default');
```

Comment: If I active any other theme, will it give me back that theme name?

Comment: This will return the theme which is set to 'Active and default'. So, if you change the default theme, it will return the name of that theme :-)